# undefined is not an object axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm getting this error when i try to use GET method in AXIOS. At the bottom I put a code snippet without style. Wants to grab data from the API using AXIOS. I'm new and don't quite know how to do this correctly.

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.map')

code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const [categoryIndex, setCategoryIndex, data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux',
            );
            setData(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView
            <ul>
                {data.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.objectID}>
                        <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: You seem to expecting two pairs of state/setter back from a single call to useState...

Answer (score 0):

- Hi, your data is not like you expected. There is also "hits" variable that exists, I think you want to show that data.
- In the first render, it's trying to map your data but data was not filled when trying to map it.
- Also, you should be re-examined "useState" usage.
- And you need to check if data exist before the map it (data?.hits).
- And you forgot to close the SafeAreaViewtag.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-fast-pdqhy?file=/src/TestApp.jsx

If you paste this it will work correctly:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [categoryIndex, setCategoryIndex] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux"
      );
      console.log(result);
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ul>
        {data?.hits &&
          data.hits.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.objectID}>
              <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but i have now this error "View config getter callback for component 'ul' must be a function (reveived 'undefidned'). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter."

Comment: I think there is a problem in your SafeAreaView. If you delete this component and use directly ul element its gonna work. You should edit your component.